# Amazon Echo development: ways to set shouldEndSession

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-echo, alexa-skills-kit

How should I set the `shouldEndSession` to be false in my intent handler?

I tried to do something like:

```
response.shouldEndSession(false);
```

But it didn't work. I'm using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Node.js, you should be able to do the following:

```js
response.shouldEndSession(false, "Reprompt your user here");
```

If you're using just plain Javascript and just setting the value in your return object, you want to include the following if your response:

```js
{
...
  "reprompt": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Reprompt your user here"
    }
  },
  "shouldEndSession": false
}
```